# How can I use the parameters of a function inside a nested function?

Tags: python, scope

I get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'weights' referenced before assignment`

How can I get the nested function to be defined based on the weights variable?

```py
def create_defender(weights=None):

    def defender(position_1, position_2):
        if not weights:
            weights = [ 1, 1.25, 1.5]
        ...
        return something

    return defender
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.learnpython.org/en/Closures

> Firstly, a Nested Function is a function defined inside another function. It's very important to note that the nested functions can access the variables of the enclosing scope. However, at least in python, they are only readonly. However, one can use the "nonlocal" keyword explicitly with these variables in order to modify them.

e.g:

```py
def defender(position_1, position_2):
        nonlocal weights
        if not weights:
            weights = [ 1, 1.25, 1.5]
```

should do what you're looking for.